# Write complex numbers to binary file in definite format with Python

Tags: python, file, binary, complex-numbers

I'm looking to write Python complex numbers to a binary file in a definite
format, so a non-Python-based tool can open the file later and read and
understand the data. The format (see below) of real part then imag part in
bytes is a hard requirement.

So if I have variables:
 `myVar1 =  0.123+0.456j myVar2 =  0.246+0.357j`

I want to write them in binary to a file, such that this will be the
first 16 bytes of the file (BE, but ignore endian issues for now):

```
  AAAAAAAA_BBBBBBBB_XXXXXXXX_YYYYYYY
  3DFBE76C 3EE978D5 3E7BE76C 3EB6C8B4
```

Where:

```
  3DFBE76C - real part/0.123 of myVar1 as a 32-bit float 
  3EE978D5 - imag part/0.456 of myVar1 as a 32-bit float
  3E7BE76C - real part/0.246 of myVar2 as a 32-bit float
  3EB6C8B4 - imag part/0.357 of myVar2 as a 32-bit float
```

I've tried to write `myVar1.real` and then `myVar1.imag` but the floating point
prevents me from using something like `write((x).to_bytes(4, byteorder='big'))`

Any suggestions?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can use numpy to specify the exact storage size of a number; I'd think you could use [`numpy.single`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.single) to store the real and imaginary parts. Does that help?

Comment: "but ignore endian issues for now": But that's the reason why exchange formats are usually something text-based, like json or xml.

Comment: Thanks RD. numpy.single did what I needed.